# How to use JSON.parse with bucket_script?

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have a data field saved with JSON string and I need to count the average value of price in `"{price: 10}"`, how do I use JSON.parse with bucket_script to compute this with elastic search?

Answer (score 0):

There is no JSON parsing class in painless So you cannot perform this while querying. You should parse JSOn while indexing this will make your search queries faster.

1. Ingest

You can use [JSON Precessor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/json-processor.html)

```
{
  "json" : {
    "field" : "string_source",
    "target_field" : "json_target"
  }
}
```

**Pipeline**

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/my-pipeline
{
  "description": "describe pipeline",
  "processors": [
    {
      "json": {
        "field": "string_source",
        "target_field": "json_target"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Index document using ingest pipeline**

```
POST json_index/_doc?pipeline=my-pipeline
{
   "string_source":"{\"price\":10}"
}
```

**Document**

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "json_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "m7t3gXEB1B5aJp__0oos",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "json_target" : {
            "price" : 10
          },
          "string_source" : """{"price":10}"""
        }
      }
    ]
```

If you don't want to keep original string in index you can use

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/my-pipeline
{
  "description": "describe pipeline",
  "processors": [
    {
      "json": {
        "field": "string_source",
        "target_field": "json_target"
      },
      "remove": {
        "field": "string_source"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**2. [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html#plugins-filters-json-remove_field)**

> This is a JSON parsing filter. It takes an existing field which contains JSON and expands it into an actual data structure within the Logstash event.

```
    filter {
      json {
        source => "message"
      }
    }
```